# Find out data traffic coming in and going out through azure VM

Tags: azure, azure-virtual-machine, azure-powershell

Is there any mechanism we can track data going in or flowing out from an azure vm ? I guess this mechanism is there for amazon VMs under cloud watch. I can't see anything related to this on azure portal under virtual machine tab. Any PS command or anything for this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, from the virtual machine blade, right click the Monitoring web part, select Edit Chart, and then select the **Network In** and **Network Out** metrics.

[image]

Comment: How is this calculated? How does azure calculate the network in and network out metrics?